# Need help in assignment task in logic proof field!

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

We are currently struggling with this task in an exercise session. The problem is that none of us are that much familiar with proofing and this seems quite difficult. The task it self says:

A list represents a sequence of elements, e.g, $l_1 = [a,b,c]$ or $l_2 = [1,2,3,5,7,11]$ are two lists. The head of a non-empty list is its left-most element (1st element) and the tail of a list is a list containing all the elements except the head. Let $h$ show the head of a non-empty list $l$ and $t$ show its tail, we show the list $l$ by $h :: t$.

The predicate ${\rm take}(l,n,l_0)$ shows that the list $l_0$ contains the first $n$ elements of $l$. The function ${\rm length}(l)$ is defined as follows: 
$$\begin{cases}
\forall h~\forall t~{\rm length}(h :: t) = 1 + {\rm length}(t) \\
{\rm length}([]) = 0
\end{cases}$$

Prove

$$[{\rm take}(l,n,l_0)] \implies {\rm length}(l_0) \le {\rm length}(l)$$

Note that if $l = l_0$, then ${\rm length}(l) = {\rm length}(l_0)$.

Comment: Your definition of `take` is a bit unclear — specifically, the meaning of "contains" in *"`take(l,n,l0)` [means] that the list `l0` contains the ﬁrst n elements of `l`"* Do you mean that `l` and `l0` agree in the first `n` places? The statement you're supposed to prove does *not* follow: in fact, it's not clear what it means. Is `n` quantified? Do you mean "if (`for all `n`, `take(l, n, l0)`), then `len(l0)` ≤ `len(l)`"? or "if (for some `n`, ...) then ___" ?

Comment: Yeah, well that's the problem. It's exactly how it is written in the task it self, but we can't understand how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: Ask your teacher to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

the statement length(l')<=length(l) is a valid logical formula that you should prove. Note that we define many predicates based on mathematical formulae, e.g. the predicate square(n,m) holds if m is the square of n defined as (m=n*n). You may rewrite this as a predicate if you like to, but you can prove it without that as well.

Comment: ∀h∀t.(length(h :: t) = 1 + length(t)) length([]) = 0
Prove [take(l, n, l′)] → lenght(l′) <= length(l) Note that if l = l′, then length(l) = length(l′).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to prove isn't a true statement.  For example, consider

$$l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$$
$$n = 2$$
$$l_0 = [1, 2, 3]$$

Then you have

$${\rm take}(l, n, l_0) \implies {\rm length}(l) \le {\rm length}(l_0)$$
$${\rm take}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, [1, 2, 3]) \implies 5 \le 3$$
$$\text{true} \implies \text{false}$$

Comment: I think you got it the other way around? Shouldn't it suppose to be l = [1,2,3] and l0 = [1,2,3,4,5] ? The the statement becomes true? Or am I not getting something?